# Mongoose - increase limit of selected items

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose 4.0.7 with MongoDB 2.4.14, and the number of items I can fetch with a find({}) query is limited to 1000. I can't find any way to increase this limit....

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the limit param?

```
var myLimit = 5000;

exampleModel.find({}).limit(myLimit).exec(function (err, results) {
   //...
});
```